# move_uploaded_file: no such file when another directory is used

Tags: php, file, path, directory, move

I am using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23981045/2411320), where they use:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

which works like a charm, if I create an 'uploads' directory inside the 'php' directory that executes this code.

If I try to do this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '../img/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

I am getting this warning:

[image]

What am I missing here? I tried with absolute path too!

Directory tree:

```
scouter
  -img
  -php
    -uplodas
    -upload.php
```

'img' directory seems to have the needed permission options.

---

EDIT_0:

If I place the file in `uploads` dir and then use `rename()` it will place the file in `img` dir...Can't get what is happening!

---

EDIT_1:

HTML:

```
<input id="input_pic" type='file' name='userFile'/>
<div>
  <img class="profile_pic" src="img/newname.jpg" alt="player_img" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
var file_data = $('#input_pic').prop('files')[0];   
var form_data = new FormData();                  
form_data.append('file', file_data);
alert(form_data);                             
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/upload.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,                         
    type: 'post',
    success: function(php_script_response){
      alert(php_script_response);
    }
});
```

---

EDIT_2:

The server response, from the answer of swidmann:

[image]

Comment: > I am getting the warning. - What's the warning text? And please ensure about the `img` directory permissions - is is writable?

Comment: You can use `'./img/' . $_FILES['file']['name']`, one dot instead two.. :D

Comment: I updated, sorry! Yes it is. @EkoJunaidiSalam that didn't make any difference, rather than the warning message, which now has one dot instead of two. :)

Comment: you need another `../`

Comment: @Fred-ii- you mean `'../../img/'`? Same effect! :/

Comment: that folder also needs write permissions. 755 or last resort, 777,

Comment: do you have a defined variable where it represents `scouter` folder ??

Comment: img folder has 777 permissions.

Comment: what if you try `__DIR__` with `str_replace()` instead of relative `../img/` ?

Comment: @Andrew I do not understand, I am a newbie in PHP. @Mi-C* this is what I am trying, but I can't make it seem correct in syntax. Can you provide an example, even as an answer?

Comment: try a full system path `/home/users1/std10093/public_html/scouter/img/`

Comment: @Fred-ii- same! I also tried with `dirname(__FILE__)`, but no luck again.

Comment: @gsamaras, how about creating another folder in same level with `img`, and try your code with the new folder?

Comment: I did that with `uploads` dir and it works like a charm. The problem only occurs when I try to write to `img` dir. @Mi-Creativity

Comment: but the `uploads` folder is not on the same level with `img` folder

Comment: Oh sorry. Same result with what you suggested @Mi-Creativity! :/

Comment: While this mostly won't make a difference, just give it a try: `$tempPath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; $filePath = '../img/' . $_FILES['file']['name']; move_uploaded_file($tempPath, $filePath);`

Comment: No luck @Mi-Creativity... :/

Comment: @gsamaras, I've updated my answer, maybe you can check this: `move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/test/scouter/img/".$_FILES['file']['name'] );`

Comment: I had tried that on some phase @swidmann. I tried that now again, no luck!

Comment: @gsamaras: you are using **userFile** as name in your HTML and **file** as name in your PHP,  how could this work?

Comment: This works @swidmann, because in the JS code I know from where do I have to grasp the image. It must a leftover, but it's not an error, really.

Comment: Maybe you should show us you AJAX call

Comment: @Fred-ii- just wanted to say THANK YOU for all you do for everyone on the stack. You make the stack a better place. The appreciation is never lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an other name in your HTML, I somehow doubt, that this was working before, your HTML:

```
<input id="input_pic" type='file' name='userFile'/>
```

Due to the php it should be:

```
<input id="input_pic" type='file' name='file'/>
```

or your php should use:

```
$_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name']
```

I think your problem is maybe the upload size, try this to debug:

```
    var_dump( $_FILES );
    $upload = move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ).'/img/'. $_FILES['file']['name'] );
    var_dump( $upload );
    var_dump( ini_get("upload_max_filesize") );// what is allowed and how big is your picture?
    var_dump( $_FILES['file']['size']  );// if this is 0, maybe your allowed upload size is to low
```

By the way I tried this and it worked:

```
dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ).'/img/'
```

To change the allowed upload size, you have to change the following options:
Set `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php.ini.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

If this is all OK, please try the absolute path:

```
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/test/scouter/img/".$_FILES['file']['name'] );
```

Comment: it uploads it to `/uploads/` folder but not to `../img/` so i don't think it is a size problem

Comment: is it always the same picture? And where is your form, do you include upload.php or do you post it to the upload php?

Comment: Hi, I am not suspecting the size either, because of what Mi-C* said, but I will take a look at your answer. Check my updated question please for the HTML.

Comment: @Mi-Creativity: the path is different, because I added the `test` folder from the error message

Comment: Your debug code gives me an error. `unexpected $end`.

Comment: I guess you are right. Updated my question with your debug output! However, it doesn't say much *to me*.

Comment: That worked: `dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ).'/img/'` bravo!